# What is the proper way to handle multiple edittext in one cell in list view?

Tags: android, listview

I have created list view with cell like this.

[image]

but now problem is when i click on "Qty" edit text list view getview method calling again and focus goes to "item" edit text again.

I have tried to request focus on click event of "Qty" edit text then it continuously calling getView method.

here is getview code

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int i, View layout, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
     final ViewHolder holder;
            if( layout == null ){
                //We must create a View:
                layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orderviewcapturevalue, viewGroup, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.atvItemName = (AutoCompleteTextView) layout.
                        findViewById(R.id.atvItemName);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, arrOrderLineNames);

                holder.atvItemName.setThreshold(2);
                holder.atvItemName.setAdapter(adapter);
                holder.tvRate = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvRate);
                holder.etQuantity = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.etQuantity);
                holder.tvCaptureTotal = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.tvCaptureTotal);
                layout.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) layout.getTag();
            }

          holder.etQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.atvItemName.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                    holder.etQuantity.requestFocus();
                    holder.etQuantity.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                }

            });
}
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51454770/7666442

Comment: By the way you should use RecyclerView

Comment: @ArbazPirwani Is there any specific reason for use RecyclerView?Means why we cannot handle in Listview?

Comment: yes here is a lot of things 

by it names it recycle your view only the preview item in the screen take place in memory and the other are not take memory plus it may help you achieving you this

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

EditText edittextobject = findVieById(R.id.edt_id);
EditText etHasFocus;

```
edittextobject.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {  
                   

                        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                            if (etHasFocus != null) {

                                if (etHasFocus.getId() != view.getId()) {

                                    etHasFocus = (EditText) view;
                                   
                                }
                            } else {
                                etHasFocus = (EditText) view;

                            }

                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

And try focus on this **etHasFocus.requestFocus();** not directly on **edittextobject** this.